# Javascript Optimization: Is it a good idea to index object properties?

Tags: javascript, performance

Let's say I'm making a game where each sprite has a large number of properties (say, over 300), which must be accessed regularly in frame update operations.  Speed is the main concern: Is it faster to pack each property in its own group?  For example, I can use this.xspeed and this.yspeed, or I can use this.physics.xspeed and this.physics.yspeed, using a small number of top-level properties.  How efficient is Javascript at "finding" an object property in a large list of other properties versus navigating a "tree" of properties?  Is there a point where one becomes more efficient than the other?

Comment: please post your code............

Comment: Benchmark it both ways. As a general rule: any property access is virtually instantaneous, there's virtually no difference depending on how many properties there are. However, each access has a slight overhead of course, so nested property access is likely slower. In practice, the difference is likely not even measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely to depend on the the JavaScript engine running the code, but by using `this.physics.xspeed` instead of `this.xspeed`, you're doing *two* property lookups instead of one. So the question is: Will two separate lookups on objects with smaller sets of properties ever be faster than one lookup on an object with a lot of properties? And the answer to that is probably engine-specific, but likely to be "no" on modern JavaScript engines like V8 in Chrome or SpiderMonkey in Firefox.

Most modern JavaScript engines don't treat objects as key/value maps anymore, they optimize aggressively by doing things like creating on-the-fly classes to represent the object (so it doesn't matter how many properites there are, finding it is just indexing into the memory for the object). This is why, if you have a set of objects that all have the same properties (a "class"), it's important to initialize all of the properties for the object up front and in the same order on all code paths that create the objects. (More in the [V8 Fast Property Access](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Design%20Elements#fast-property-access) article on the V8 wiki.)

Obviously you'd want to benchmark your actual code in your actual environment, but [a quick jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/access-time-on-big-vs-small-object) suggests that neither Chrome nor Firefox cares if the object has 10 or 500 properties, so adding a second level would only make things slower. (I couldn't measure on IE11, got "infinity" for the 10-property object. Don't have Edge handy right now.)